# How do I play the entire tone in background in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, alarm

I made an alarm app by first registering the user data using SQLite and I was also able to schedule a notification using the flutter_local_notifications package......Can someone tell me how do I play the alarm tone in the background until the user shuts it down?
Which dependency should I use to play the alarm tone as you can only schedule a 3-sec tone with the flutter_local_notification package?

Answer (score 0):

as i understand your issue you should use `flutter_background_service` package which i pasted the link here. it's A flutter plugin for execute dart code in background.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service